# PowerShell - User session management

Tags: powershell, session, user-management, usersession

I have this PowerShell script that logs off users with IDLE time greater that 1 hour:

```
#Force script to run.
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -force
#Check connected users and save output.
quser|out-file C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\disconectAgora\quser.txt
#Read output with logged in users.
$file = Get-Content C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\disconectAgora\quser.txt

#Obtain IDLE time by using patters.
$pattern = "Disc(.*?)11"
#Obtaons session ID by using patther.
$pattern2 = "adminagora(.*?)Disc"


#Execute query using above patterns.
$result = [regex]::Match($file,$pattern).Groups[1].Value
$result2 = [regex]::Match($file,$pattern2).Groups[1].Value

#Trim file and save both session id and username.

$result = $result -replace(' ','')
$result |out-file C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\disconectAgora\getDCUser.txt

$result2 = $result2 -replace(' ','')
$result2 |out-file C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\disconectAgora\getDCUserID.txt

#If IDLE time is greater than 1 hour user is disconnected.
if ($result -gt '1:00'){    
    logoff $result2
    }
else{
    write-host "No users with IDLE time greater than 1 hour found.No users to be logged off."
    }
```

What I want to do is check if a cmd process is running or not, so the user can remain logged on untill this process has ended.

I tought that maybe by running this command `get-process | where-object {$_.mainwindowhandle -ne 0} | select-object name, mainwindowtitle` and using regex to get only cmd processes it might do the trick, but it is a very primitive approach.

If you guys have any clue as to how to go about doing this, please let me know.

As requested, here's the output of quser:

[image]

**Long story short**

I need a way to know if something is being executed by **CMD** other than checking the CPU usage:

[image]

Comment: You should post the actual code instead of screenshots.  If someone wants to try it out, they aren't going to sit and re-type it in order to help you.

Comment: You are right, thanks

Comment: I think most of your code could be shortened with a RegEx using named capture groups if you show us a sample output of your (presumably localized) `quser`

Comment: Why the `11` in `$pattern`?

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers, it was for testing puropses, when I execute `quser` the part that i want to extract is between Disc and the logon time. In this case `11` was the day of month.

Comment: @LotPings I have added the output on the main body of the question

Comment: I suggest you take a look at [this help article](https://www.itdroplets.com/get-list-users-logged-list-servers-powershell/) to the topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get cmd processes just run `get-process -name cmd`

To find any child processes within cmd you could use something like this:

```
Get-WmiObject win32_process | where {$_.ParentProcessId -eq ((Get-Process -name cmd).id)}
```

Upd.
As @LievenKeersmaekers has noticed this could not work in case of several cmds running simultaneously. Fixed version:

```
(Get-Process -name cmd).id | foreach { Get-WmiObject win32_process -filter "ParentProcessId='$_'"}
```

Comment: Yes, that helps but in essence what I want is some datathat lets me know if something is running on cmd. I could use the CPU usage as a reference, but I dont think is a reliable marker.

Comment: It depends on what is exactly executed within cmd. In a general case it could be only done by a trial and error.

Comment: You could also find child processes of cmd. This could be a slight evidence that something is executing within cmd.

Comment: Note that this is not foolproof. If you have two or more `cmd` processes running and a busy child process on another than the first `cmd`, this will not return a result.

Comment: This will also not detect a cmd that by itself is running some code but your definition of a running process on `cmd` is not clear. What do you consider a running process? Because after all, every process returned by Get-Process is running.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers Thanks for noticing, I've made a change that should detect child processes for all running cmds. Regarding some code that is running by cmd itself - there's not much internal cmd commands that could take any significant time.

Answer (score 1):

Following is a bit simplified and returns the users, other than `adminagora`, that have disconnected sessions for over an hour

```
(& quser) -split "`n" | ? {$_ -match "(?<!adminagora).*?Disc\s+\d:\d{2}"}
```

**breakdown**

```
(& quser) -split "`n"  -- Executes quser 
                          Splits each line on newline to pass through the pipeline
? {$_ -match           -- Where the current item matches the regex
(?<!adminagora)        -- Use a negative lookbehind to exclude adminagora
.*?Disc                -- match any characters as few times as possible up until Disc. 
\s+\d:\d{2}            -- match any space character followed by
                       -- a digit, a colon and two digits
```

Comment: Wow, that does indeed simplify my script. But the main thing is how i determine if something is running on cmd, I could guide me thru the CPU usage, but I'm not to keen on that.